# maven error: A required class was missing while executing

Tags: java, maven

Presento el siguiente error al momento de tratar de ejecutar cualquier proyecto web en netbeans 12.1.

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on
> project simoau: Execution default-war of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: A required
> class was missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war:
> org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
> ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3 strategy =
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.3/maven-war-plugin-2.3.jar
>
> urls[3] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
> urls[4] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
> urls[5] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
> urls[6] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.5/plexus-io-2.0.5.jar
> urls[7] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
> urls[8] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
> urls[9] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
> urls[10] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar
> urls[11] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
> urls[12] =
> file:/C:/Users/wolfc/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
> Number of foreign imports: 1 import: Entry[import  from realm
> ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
>
> ----------------------------------------------------- : org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException
> -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
> read the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto suele ser un problema de alguno de los plugins que estás añadiendo, en el caso de que no sepas la dependencia exacta de cada uno de ellos, te recomiendo probar a eliminar  `.m2/repository`, por lo menos a mí me ha funcionado alguna vez.

 Te dejo un enlace de ayuda el cual me sirvió a mí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp